# How to download file depending on user input in html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, javascript-objects

Please I am a total javascript noob, I can find my way around some basic html/css but don't even know where to begin on this.

I need a form that is able to download a pdf file based on the users entry.

If a user enters the password and hit enter key or download button, the pdf file for that password  gets downloaded.

If a user enters file123, the 123.pdf file gets downloaded.

It is jus one field with the label 'password' and if the correct password is submitted, a file is automatically downloaded

This is the form i've made so far

```
<form action="">
<span class="text-red">Invalid Code</span>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
<input type="text" class="password" value="" required/>
<input  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.